# Binding to alternative IP in HttpWebRequest doesn't work in Windows Server 2008

Tags: sockets, httpwebrequest

I am trying to bind a HttpWebRequest call to a specific IP on my server (which has many IPs). I have successfully written this code using BindIPEndPointDelegate and it works well on my local machine (Windows 7)

My issue is with Windows Server 2008. When I run the same console app on Windows Server 2008 it fails to bind to the IP when using the delegate. To complicate matters further, it seems to work for some destination URLs (http://www.microsoft.com) and doesn't work for some (http://www.google.com, http://www.facebook.com)

If I remove the IP specific binding (delegate) and run the app it works for all URLs.

The IP I am binding to is the default server IP address - meaning, in both scenarios the same IP should be used. I have verified this and it uses the same IP if I don't bind using the delegate. If I explicitly specific the IP it fails as described above.

I have tried turning off firewall, IIS & Antivirus - the problem persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright finally figured it out.

Upon testing again I found that specifying IPAddress.Any did not work either. On the other hand, IPAddress.IPv6Any worked fine.

Finally, I unchecked the IPv6 protocol in network adapter settings and the app starting working properly for all URLs and binding for all local IPv4 addresses.

Not sure if this is a bug in .NET code or feature - but disabling IPv6 fixed it for me.

Lastly, if anyone is facing "The requested address is not valid in its context" while making calls with binding, try disabling your antivirus.